# Zend Framework Redirect and Routes, somehow not working

Tags: zend-framework, redirect, routes

I've been trying to wrap my head around routing and for that very reason build a small aplication to fiddle around with, but i've managed to stumble upon a problem.

The goal of the whole test was to hide the url 'hostname/content/index/add' and turn it into a url more understandable for a user like 'hostname/wms/content/add'.

But now for some odd reason i cannot redirect using the $this->url() methode. But somehow a normal link like somelink work.

I have build a few routes in the application.ini to test how it works. It's nothing fancy...

```
resources.router.routes.contentroute.route = "/wms/content"
resources.router.routes.contentroute.defaults.module = content
resources.router.routes.contentroute.defaults.controller = index
resources.router.routes.contentroute.defaults.action = index

resources.router.routes.vacaturesroute.route = "/wms/vacatures"
resources.router.routes.vacaturesroute.defaults.module = vacatures
resources.router.routes.vacaturesroute.defaults.controller = index
resources.router.routes.vacaturesroute.defaults.action = index
```

So when i type hostname/wms/content i get redirected to the content module's IndexController and it's IndexAction. This works fine for all the links in my views that point to the content module like this

```
<a href='wms/content/'> link </a>
```

However it's not working for 3 links that actually redirect towards a specific action of the IndexController on that very page hostname/wms/content.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'add'));?>">Add new content</a>
```

Instead of actually redirecting towards the add action in the IndexController i get redirected to hostname/wms/content, wich is the page i'm comming from.

Anyone have an idea why this is happening and possibly a way to solve this? Or am i totally approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your route are static ones. You should replace them with:

```
resources.router.routes.contentroute.route = "/wms/content/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.contentroute.defaults.module = content
resources.router.routes.contentroute.defaults.controller = index
resources.router.routes.contentroute.defaults.action = index
```

Then, you should specify the name of your route and pass true in reset argument:

```
$this->url(
  array('module'=>'content', 'controller'=>'index','action'=>'add'), 
  'contentroute', 
  true
);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This solved the issue indeed. I was unaware that it's required to add '/:action/*' to the route, or the need to specify the route itself.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'add','module'=>'xyz'),null,true);?>">Add new content</a>
```

Replace xyz with your module name.

Comment: If you pass null in the name param, it takes the default route.

Comment: @Maxence routes are not defined for this url , check the config posted by op .

Comment: You're right. I think his config is wrong, but your answer works in this case. Sorry.

Comment: Your answer indeed also works, thou i prefer the answer given by Maxence since i will be using multiple routes and links in the completed application.